# How to create array as a property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a function that generates random Integers from a certain interval and each time it is called, it should produce a unique one. For that I have created this `generateUniqueInt`.

```js
    function generateUniqueInt() {
        var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        while (generateUniqueInt.used.indexOf(res) !== -1)
            res = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        generateUniqueInt.used.push(res);
        return res;
    }
    generateUniqueInt.used = new Array;

    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        console.log(generateUniqueInt());
    }

    generateUniqueInt.used.sort();
    console.log(generateUniqueInt.used);
```

I called this function few times like this and it works. 
Then I wanted to check which values were actually generated and for easier inspection I sorted the `used` property. But as it seems, `used` is not an array anymore.

I have tried using `generateUniqueInt.used = [];` as well as `Object.defineProperty` but the outcome is the same each time. What am I missing here? Is there a way to create `used` as an array?

Comment: What makes you think it's not an array after sorting?

Comment: [Cant reproduce!](http://jsbin.com/noqeguheqa/edit?console)

Comment: I ran your code in chrome console and it worked for me, `generateUniqueInt.used` was an array with 20 values

Comment: That seems to be an interesting question, but the copy past of your code works just fine.

Comment: @JonasW. If I ask what is the type of items inside of `used`, the answer is Number but sorting doesn't work the same as if it was an array of numbers, check the outcome, it is not sorted that way.

Comment: `sort()` sorts alphanumerically by default, `ab > aa` therefore `12 > 112`. If you want to sort numerically: `.sort((a,b) => a - b)`

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks. For some reason I thought otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is :`The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

So below code will return following output:

```
var array1 = [1, 30, 4, 21];
array1.sort();
console.log(array1);
// expected output: Array [1, 21, 30, 4]
```

In order to solve for numbers you will may follow example from MDN:

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(numbers);

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So your example would become following which should give you correct desired output:

```
generateUniqueInt.used.sort(function(a,b){ return a - b});
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the sort method sorts elements alphabetically, so your array will be sorted like `[1,2,25,3,4 ...]`

use this to sort an array of numbers :

```
generateUniqueInt.used.sort(function(a,b){ return a - b});
```

```js
let arr = [4,2,65,12,23,5,3]

let sorted1 = arr.sort()
console.log('sorted alphabetically : ', JSON.stringify(sorted1))

let sorted2 = arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a - b})
console.log('sorted numerically : ', JSON.stringify(sorted2))
```